# Como editar a mensagem ( Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded )

Tags: php

Toda vez que há uma lentidão na resposta do servidor essa mensagem é exibida, mas ela não é formatada e foge do padrão de layout da minha aplicação.

Gostaria de saber se é possível editar essa mensagem ou tratá-la, tipo modificar cor da fonte, coisas do tipo.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode editar esta mensagem, mas pode capturar o erro fatal usando as funções [register_shutdown_function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) e [error_get_last](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) e tratá-lo de maneira diferente.

```
<?php

function onShutdown() {
    $lastError = error_get_last();
    if ($error['type'] == E_ERROR) {
        // Retornar seu template com erro
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('onShutdown');
```

Você provavelmente terá que alterar o seu `php.ini` para não exibir erros com `display_errors=0` também.